# Image is displaying pixelated in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I am displaying a .Jpg Image in my Website. Image Looks Good in Firefox , Chrome but in IE it looks Pixelated. I am using IE9.

my Code:

```
<img src="../TestApp/images/Pic.jpg" border="0" Style="width:770px;height:auto;margin:0px;padding:0px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"  />
```

I tried  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; That Did not work **Since it is obsolete**

I tried -ms-interpolation-mode:nearest-neighbor;

I tried

```
<div class="column">
<img src="../TestApp/images/Pic.jpg" border="0" Style="width:770px;height:auto;margin:0px;padding:0px; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" class="Plate"/>  
</div>  


.column {
float:left;
display:inline; /* prevent IE margin doubling */
width:360px;
padding-top:1em;
margin-right:60px;
text-align:left;
}

.plate {
display:block;
margin:0 auto 0.5em;
}
```

That Didn't work. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What are the intrinsic dimensions of the image?

Comment: Why all the random capitals? Not only do they make your post difficult to read, but they also actively cause problems in your code.

Comment: If you need a thumnbail please try: https://github.com/Lygin/ie-bicubic-img-interpolation-plugin/wiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing width:770px;height:auto; from image and sizing the image to 770px in photoshop and uploading it to the images folder.

Comment: Correct, Chrome and FF are much better at up- or downscaling images than IE. Only good solution is to use vector images (SVG) or display images at their actual size (always do that if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't use the more computationally-intensive algorithm (e.g. Lanczos, Bi-Cubic, etc.) to scale images that the other browser vendors use.

I would suggest detecting IE in the browser and using the exact dimensions of the image to avoid scaling.

However this is not the ideal solution, as responsive web design does call for serving a slightly different size image, and allowing the context to scale the image appropriately, ideally down-sized.